# Phplist Database error 1146

Tags: database, email, phplist

I just configured and upload phplist to my webpage and when I try to acces it I get this error:

```
Database error 1146 while doing query Table 'tramvaji_mail.phplist_subscribepage' doesn't exist
Database error 1146 while doing query Table 'tramvaji_mail.phplist_subscribepage' doesn't exist
Database error 1146 while doing query Table 'tramvaji_mail.phplist_subscribepage' doesn't exist
```

Can somebody please help me?

Answer (score 14):

Did you see this while going to `http://domain-name/lists` ?

if yes, try to go to `http://domain-name/lists/admin` to finish your installation first

Comment: This is correct. 1st step: Create the database, see phplist\lists\config\config.php for db settings. 2nd step: Modify db settings after database creation. 3rd step (optional): Modify  SMTP-settings in phplist\lists\config\config.php. 4th step: go to phplist/lists/admin